# Двойной клик для закрытия дропдауна

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, angularjs, angular

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Что бы закрыть дроп при клике ИМЕННО на последнем элементе требуется двойной клик, на все остальных элементах все работает как и положено при первом клике. Может кто стыкался с такой проблемой и знает ее решение.

```html
                    <div class="bulk-actions arrow condition" uib-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick"
                         on-toggle="$ctrl.bulkOpen = !$ctrl.bulkOpen">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <div class="opener">
                                <button class="btn btn-white" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                                    {{$ctrl.assignKeeper.name || 'N/A'| translate}}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown" uib-dropdown-menu ng-if="$ctrl.bulkOpen">
                                <ul>
                                    <li ng-repeat="keeper in $ctrl.housekeepers" uib-dropdown-toggle 
                                    ng-click="$ctrl.selectKeeper(keeper)">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link">
                                            <span class="room">{{ keeper.name }}</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Для начала нужен работающий пример.

Comment: Можно (но не нужно) написать вот такой вот костыль: document.querySelectorAll('.btn')[document.querySelectorAll('.btn').length - 1].addEventListener('click', function(){ this.click() });